# Rebasing Git Repo with Python

Tags: python, git

Is there a way to use use python to rebase a repo from one on github, then push the result. As well as detecting if the rebase failed as a result of conflicts that need to be resolved?

Comment: Yep, that's possible.

Comment: As written, this question is either too broad or not clear enough for stackoverflow.  Pick some part of the problem, like perhaps interacting with GIT from python and focus your question on that.  Tell us what you've already tried and what your research has found.

Comment: That is my problem, I need to interact with git using python. Even more specific I need to rebase a git repo from python and see if everything was alright.

Comment: You could use `pygit2` or `commands.getstatusoutput("git command")`.

Answer (score -1):

Git is primarily a command-line tool.  Once installed, you should be able to open-up a console, command prompt, powershell, c-shell, bash shell, etc. and just type `git` and get a list of available git commands.

Once you have Git setup and working this way, then from Python it would be possible to execute git commands in the same way you would execute any other shell commands.  I'm not a Python expert, but [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) suggests in the comments to use:

```
commands.getstatusoutput("git <command>")
```

You will need to do a separate search for `git rebase` specifically and figure out how the output is formatted and parse it to determine success, or possibly there is an error code or StdErr output that you can get through the `.getstatusoutput` or a similar command from `commands` in python.

Another thing that may help is looking at the man page for rebase with `git rebase --help`.

#### Summary

I recommend doing a search to find out more about the python `commands` library or just shell interaction in general for python, and then a separate set of searches/research to determine exactly how to implement the `git rebase` commands and its output format to determine what you need to parse to determine success or failure.